# gnome-terminal: can't access url from the terminal by single click

Tags: command-line, mouse, gnome-terminal, url

I want to access the url that is printed on the command line. For example, if I see the `man` pages for `dropbox`, there are some url links with underlines (i.e. `https://www.dropbox.com/`)--

[image]

The only way to access this url is to do right click and copy the link.

Is there anyway I can access it using a single click?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> whilst clicking on the link.

You can also right-click on it and press <kbd>Open Link</kbd>

[image]

It that does not work, try running `man -Tutf8 dropbox` to output the manual page to stdout